# Get NodeList from xml document

Tags: android, android-xml

I have developed the following class to retrieve the node-list of a xml document:

```
public class XMLDownloader {
    public static NodeList getNodeList(){   
        String url = "http://localhost/xml/example.xml";
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse res = null;
        NodeList result = null;

        try {
            res = client.execute(method);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(is);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            result = doc.getElementsByTagName("client");                         
            is.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }       
        return result;              
    }
}
```

But this method returns `null`. Any ideas?

The xml file:

```
<status>
<client type="s" name="test1" protocol="1000">
      </client>
<client type="r" name="test2" protocol="2000"> 
      </client>
<client type="r" name="test3" protocol="3000"> 
      </client>
<client type="h" name="test4" protocol="4000"> 
      </client>
<client type="c" name="test5" protocol="5000"> 
      </client>
</status>
```

Comment: can you post your example.xml file as well or point out which section is returning null for you

Comment: Are you sure that that the contents of the response entity contains the correct thing?  Use the Eclipse debugger to step through and inspect the objects at each point to make sure that the document contains what you think it does.

Comment: Did your code log an error or stack trace (from the catch clauses)? If so, what were they? (As an aside, there's no need to call normalize() here--parse always returns a normalized Document. normalize() is useful if you are modifying the doc tree in code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code posted in the question actually works for me without any errors.  I get a NodeList containing the expected 5 elements.  I tried it on an emulator running 2.2.